# Removing first case insensitive duplicate of an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have an arraylist containing some strings:

```
ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.addAll(Arrays.asList("interface", "list", "Primitive", "class", "primitive", "List", "Interface", "lIst", "Primitive"));
```

I have wrote a method to remove the case insensitive strings of the arraylist:

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> strList) {

    for(int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < strList.size(); j++) {
            if(strList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(strList.get(j))){
                strList.remove(j);
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return strList;   
}
```

Ouput:

```
[interface, list, Primitive, class]
```

However, I am trying to remove just the first occurance of the strings. I am trying to make it so my output would equal:

```
[Interface, lIst, Primitive, class]
```

Which would be the last occurrences of the duplicates in the arraylist

What I'm trying to do specifically:

> The version of the string that remains is the same as the last occurrence. In other words, the
>   version of the last occurrence stays at the location of the first occurrence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that remove from the `ArrayList` is not good idea. It is better using `Map` to create new list:

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> strList) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    strList.forEach(item -> map.put(item.toLowerCase(), item));
    return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
}
```

**Input:** `[interface, list, Primitive, class, primitive, List, Interface, lIst, Primitive]`

**Output:** `[Interface, lIst, Primitive, class]`

**P.S.**

Same with one line `Stream`, but a bit not so clear:

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> strList) {
    return new ArrayList<>(strList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toLowerCase, str -> str, (prev, next) -> next, LinkedHashMap::new)).values());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now it keeps the first occurrence, so if you want to keep the last occurrence you can just go through the list in reverse:

```
for(int i = strList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    ...
```